# Discrete valuation and divisibility

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $v$ be a discrete valuation and $R=\{x\in K\vert v(x)\ge 0\}$.
I want to show that $x$ divides $y$ in $R$ if and only if $v(x)\le v(y)$.

The left-to-right direction is pretty trivial.
The converse direction is giving me some trouble though. The best I could do is show that if $v(x)\le v(y)$ then $z\in R$ exists with $v(y)=v(xz)$, but because $v$ is not injective (only subjective), this is not sufficient, as $xz$ might not be equal to $y$.

I don't know what else to do, as I find the property "$x$ doesn't divide $y$" hard to work with.

What is the idea behind the proof of the converse?

Comment: Is $A(v)$ supposed to mean your DVR $R$?

Comment: @daruma thanks, I just mixed up some notation

Comment: Here's the rough idea. You are taking your DVR as a subring of a field $K$. So $y/x$ has valuation $v(y/x)=v(y)-v(x)\geq 0$. This is in $R$ by definition.